# Run multiple dotnet api's project in the same EC2 on linux and apache

Tags: .net, linux, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have two dotnet projects that published on a Linux EC2 AWS instance, the 1st project is on port 5000 and the other on 50003.
I made two files in conf.d folder the 1st :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/hellomvc-error.log
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/hellomvc-access.log common
```

and the other :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5003/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5003/
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/hellomvc-error.log
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/hellomvc-access.log common
```

the second one is just an API.

my problem that I can open the 1st project on the browser without any problem but I cant access the API for the 2nd project even if I can access it locally by using  curl http://localhost:5003/api/Home

Comment: What exactly are you entering in your browser address bar when you are opening 1st project, and what when trying to open second project?

Comment: 1st one I just enter the IP for example 34.65.22.102 and the 2nd i enter 34.65.22.102/api/Home

Comment: Apache needs some exact way to make a decision which site to serve. In your case it could be either (sub) domain name (for example `www.example.com` and `api.example.com`) or URI path (for example, send `/api/*` to project 2, and everything else to project 1. Which way do you want it to be?

Comment: I am new to this, can you tell me how the 2nd project conf file should look like to be able to call the API correctly by using URI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have two distinct domain names for 1st project and 2nd project, you can try using only one VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ProxyPreserveHost On

# send /api paths to project2
ProxyPass /api http://127.0.0.1:5003/api
ProxyPassReverse /api http://127.0.0.1:5003/api

# and everything else to project1
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/

ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/hellomvc-error.log
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/hellomvc-access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

In case you have two back end services that use the sam path (`/api`) for example, you will have to use distinct hostnames and multiple Virtual Hosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName project1.example.com

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
  ProxyPassReverse /api http://127.0.0.1:5000/

  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/project1-error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/project1-access.log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName api1.example.com

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5003/
  ProxyPassReverse /api http://127.0.0.1:5003/

  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/api1-error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/api1-access.log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName api2.example.com

  ProxyPreserveHost On  
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5004/
  ProxyPassReverse /api http://127.0.0.1:5004/

  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/api2-error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/api2-access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Of course, project1.example.com, api1.example.com and api2.example.com would need to resolve to your server's ip address

Comment: thank you so much another question what i have to do if i want to run more API project, for example, a 3d one

Comment: I would have to ask a same question as above: how would requests to api1 and api2 differ?

Comment: that's the problem both projects start with api/ i am thinking maybe we can use the project name

Comment: can the hostname be anything I want ? or it should be a domain that I have with subdomain ? coz i don't have a domain name . and how i should call my api projects by the api2.example.com/Home ?

Comment: If you want it to be publicly resolvable and reachable by anyone, you need to buy a domain name. If you just want to test, you can pick any (for example the exact ones I used in my example), but you will need to [use a hosts file](https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_use_the_hosts_file/) to point those names to your server's ip address

Comment: the api will be called from android APP ,  so i don't need to be public. what if the 2nd project would be api/prj1/* and the second api/prj2/* can i use ProxyPass /api http://127.0.0.1:5003/api/prj1 and ProxyPass /api http://127.0.0.1:5003/api/prj2 ?  i tried that but it did't work

Comment: i didn't notice that, ok thx again you saved my day i would give 10/10 if i can :)